# QString to Const Char*

Tags: c++, constants, qstring

I'm trying to use the data from a function that returns a QString in a Const function that uses a Const Char*. The problem is basically the following :

```
int myObject::listChildProcesses([...]) const {
    // getProcessName called from : QString myObject::getProcessName() { [...] }
    const char* name = getProcessName().toLocal8Bit();
    [...]
}
```

Which returns :

```
passing 'const myObject' as 'this' argument of 'QString myObject::getProcessName()' discards qualifiers
```

So ... I think there is a constness problem here. However, I DO need to keep my constness in listChildProcess. Do you happen to know how I can solve that problem by keeping it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `myObject::getProcessName()` doesn't have a `const`  qualifier, but called for a constant object. So you should make change its signature to `QString myObject::getProcessName() const`.

Comment: Ah ! Well, this rang a bell. It made clear to me how to solve the problem. This was absolutely not here, I wasn't using the right thing in my code !
However, the answer is perfect nonetheless. Sorry for inconvenience !